# How to count vowels in a Javascript string with two functions?

Tags: javascript, string, function, count

I'm trying to write a Javascript function that counts the vowels in a string by calling another function inside that function, but when I test it in the console it returns 0.

Here is my first function that works fine and recognizes if a string is a vowel:

```
function isVowel(ch){
    var pattern = /[aeiouAEIOU]/
    return pattern.test(ch);
};
```

For the second function none of my ideas have worked.  Here are a few examples of what I have tried so far:

This one returns me a 0:

```
function countVowels(str){
var count = 0;

for(var i; i <= str.length; ++i){
    if(isVowel(i)){
        ++count;
    }
}
return count;
};
```

I also tried the above, but removing the .length after str in the for() area.

Another example, but this one gives me an error:

```
function countVowels(str){
var count = 0
var pattern = /[aeiouAEIOU]/

for(var i = 1; i <= str.length(pattern); ++i){
    if(isVowel(i)){
        ++count;
    }
}
return count;
};
```

I've tried various other functions as well, but for the sake of keeping this post relatively short I won't continue to post them.  I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good luck with "sometimes y".

Comment: Just use `str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length`.

Comment: _"This one returns me a 0"_ - of course it does, because you are only passing the loop counter `i` to `isVowel` - so you are checking whether `0` is a vowel, `1` is a vowel, etc. Numbers aren't vowels, so the result is of course 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the `g` attribute on your *String*.

`g`: global
`i`: case insensitive

[Regexp documentation](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)

```js
function countVowels(ch){
  return ch.match(/[aeiouy]/gi).length;
}

var str = "My string";
alert(countVowels(str)); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Robiseb answer is the way to go, I want to let you know why you code is not working (I'm referring your first attempt). Basically you made two mistakes in the loop:

1. As CBroe stated, you are passing `i` to your `isVowel` function. `i` is a integer representing the index of the loop, not the actual character inside the string. To get the character you can do `str.substr(i, 1)`, what means "give me one character from the position `i` inside the string".
2. You are not giving a initial value to the `i` variable. When you create a variable, it is undefined, so you can not increment it.

```js
alert(countVowels("hello"));

function countVowels(str) {
  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; ++i) {
    if (isVowel(str.substr(i, 1))) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};

function isVowel(ch) {
  var pattern = /[aeiouAEIOU]/
  return pattern.test(ch);
};
```

---

**UPDATE**: You will see that other answers use other methods to select the character inside the string from the index. You actually have a bunch of different options. Just for reference:

```
str.slice(i,i+1);
str.substring(i,i+1);
str.substr(i,1));
str.charAt(i);
str[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is the index, not the character. It should be:

```
if (isVowel(str[i])) {
    count++;
}
```

Also, `str.length(pattern)` is wrong. `length` is a property, not a function, so it should just be `str.length`.

Answer (score 0):

**You forgot to assign the value 0 to *i* variable**

And parameter for isVowel is the character, not the index of string

Here information about the JS language: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

```js
function isVowel(ch){
    var pattern = /[aeiouAEIOU]/
    return pattern.test(ch);
}

function countVowels(str){
var count = 0;

  // you forgot to assign the value to i variable
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){

  // isVowel(str[i]), not isVowel(i)
    if(isVowel(str[i])){
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}

console.log(countVowels('forgot'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should do it this way:

```
function isVowel(c){
    var lc = c.toLowerCase();
    if(lc === 'y'){
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    }
    return ['a','e','i','o','u'].indexOf(lc) > -1;
}
function countVowels(s){
    var i = 0;
    s.split('').each(function(c){
        if(isVowel(c)){
            i++;
        }
    });
    return i;
}
console.log(countVowels("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
```

Which, although less efficient and less useful than other answers, at least has the entertaining property of returning a different count 50% of the time, because sometimes Y.