# Javascript For Loop...One function in another?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Alright I cant seem to get this to work. I have one function written so far. It works great. Now I need to get my new function to call the second function.

Here is the first function:

```
function isVowelR(str) {

 if(str = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi))
    return true
 else
   return false
}
```

This one works fine. Returns true if str is a vowel. Here is the one Im stuck on though. This is what Ive tried (as well as some other stuff.

```
function countVowels(str) {
    var count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i == str.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == isVowelR(i))
        {
            ++count
        }
    }

    return count

}
```

This second function needs count how many vowels are in the string that is entered (which I figured out in a different function). But how do I get it to work if I am required to call the first function?

Comment: You need to check against `str[i]`, not `i` alone since that is the index and not the vowel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40313624/1427878 - amazing coincidence, john-ali ...

Comment: @CBroe, I agree, however I don't think the question was "how to do it?" but more of "why my code doesn't work?" :)

Comment: @Dekel he could have asked that in the existing question, instead of creating another account.

Comment: @CBroe, you'r right. I missed the open time of the other question. probably the exact same user...

Comment: Lol definitely not the same person. I just didn't see the other one. My bad. But yeah, it is more of a why isnt this working rather than a how to do it. 

Not the same person though. Promise! :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `i` variable is a number, so what you actually do is `isVowelR(0)`, `isVowelR(1)`, `isVowelR(2)` ...

You can change this to:

```
isVowelR(str[i])
```

Another option is just to check the length of the `match`:

```
str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length
```

This way you don't need to loop over each character on the string:

```
function countVowels(str) {
    return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length
}
```

Comment: Damn, sorry. Didn't see the other question opened 1 hour ago :\

Comment: yeah so i have the last one you commented, with the str.match as another function. That one doesnt require calling the isVowelR function. But is there a way to include the isVowelR function inside of the countVowels with the str.match portion?